# $X_{T-}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{T-}$ measurable.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

By definition, $\mathcal{F}_{T-}=\mathcal{F}_0 \vee \sigma(A\cap \{ t<T\}, A \in \mathcal{F}_t, t \in [0,\infty[)$.

[image]

Why is $X_{T-}$ a $\mathcal{F}_{T-}$  measurable function?

Edit:

Here's my try. By definition of $Y$,and since $X$ is right-continuous, $Y$ is a continuous process. We also know that $T$ is a $\mathcal{F}_{T-}$ measurable function, then the composition of $Y$ and $T$ gives a $\mathcal{F}_{T-}$ measurable function. However, I'm not sure this is correct, since $Y(T(\omega),\omega)$, and the second component I've somewhat disregarded...

Comment: "Since $X$ is right-continuous, $Y$ is a continuous process" --- should be "Since $X$ is cadlag, $Y$ is a left-continuous process."

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\ge 1$ and $k\ge 0$ (integers), the random variable
$$
Y_{k\cdot 2^{-n}}\cdot 1_{\{k2^{-n}< T\le (k+1)2^{-n}\}}
$$
is $\mathcal F_{T-}$-measurable. (Why?) Hence so is the sum
$$
X_01_{\{T=0\}}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty Y_{k\cdot 2^{-n}}\cdot 1_{\{k2^{-n}< T\le (k+1)2^{-n}\}},
$$
which converges pointwise to $Y_{T}$ on the event $\{T<\infty\}$ because $Y$ is left continuous.

Comment: Since T is $\mathcal{F}_{T-}$ measurable, the indicator function is also measurable. For the case when the indicator is 1, we have $k2^{-n}<T$,  and so $(Y_{k2^{-n}}1_{...})^{-1}(A)\cap \{k2^{-n}<T\}=Y_{k2^{-n}}^{-1}(A)=X_{k2^{-n}-}^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}_{k2^{-n}-}$ because $X$ is adapted.  Is this correct?

Thanks for your patience so far. I can clearly see that I'm out of my depth, even though I'm trying. I also left you a comment in a previous question of mine...   =)